# Find null space of P and rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $u$ be a unit vector in $R^n$ . The orthogonal projection onto $\{u\}^ \perp$ Is given by P= I- $uu^T$ .

a) Find N(P)

b) Prove that rank(P) =$ n-1$

I don't know how to even start part a , for part b I know that I can use $ n = $ rank(P) + $dim N(P) $ but don't really know how to prove it.

Comment: Hint: $\{u\}^\perp$ consists of all vectors orthogonal to $u$. What vectors do you think get mapped to $0$ by an *orthogonal* projection onto this space?

Answer (score 1):

Let $u,u_2,...,u_n$ form an orthonormal basis.

Note that $P u_k = u_k$ for $k =2,...n$, and $P u = 0$.

It follows that $\ker P = \operatorname{sp} \{ u \}$ and ${\cal R} A = \operatorname{sp} \{ u_2,...,u_n \}$ and so
$\operatorname{rk} P = n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that $(b)$ follows readily from $(a)$, once you know what $\mathcal{N}(P)$ looks like, for exactly the reasons stated in your comments following the question.  So I'll give you some hints to solve $(a)$.

$(a)$ Observe that $\mathbb{R}^n=\text{span}(\{u\})\oplus\text{span}(\{u\})^\perp$, and that $\text{span}(\{u\})\subset\mathcal{N}(P).$ Now just show that for $x\in\text{span}(\{u\})^\perp$ nonzero, we have $Px\neq0$.